# unable to display result

Tags: c, function, getchar

I was practicing c programming on my own. The program I wrote was a getfloat, which converted a stream of characters to floats (from K&R exercise 5-2). I used code snippets from the book which use getch and ungetch to fetch the next characters from either a buffer or the input. The problem with my code was that it Visual Studio that I was writing on was unable to print out the value after correctly did the calculation and conversion. I stepped into the program and found out that the variable c in my function became -1 instead of 10 at the end of the conversion, as supposedly. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int getch(void);
void ungetch(int c);
int getfloat(float *pn);
int main(void)
{
int ret;

    float f;
    printf("enter a float number:\n");
    ret=getfloat(&f);
    if(ret>0)
        printf("you've entered: %f",f);

if (ret == EOF) 
{
      puts("Stopped by EOF.");
} 
else 
{
      puts("Stopped by bad input.");
}

return 0;
}

int getfloat(float *pn)
{
 char c,sign,dec;
 float pow;
 while(isspace(c=getch()))
     ;
 if(!isdigit(c)&&c!=EOF&&c!='-'&&c!='+'&&c!='.')
 {
     ungetch(c);
     return 0;
 }
 sign=(c=='-')?-1:1;
 if(c=='-'||c=='+')
      c=getch();
 if(!isdigit(c))
 {
     ungetch(c);
     return -1;
 }
 for(*pn=0;c!=EOF && isdigit(c);c=getch())
     *pn=10* (*pn)+ (c-'0');  //calculate the integer part//

 if((c=getch())=='.')
 {
     for(*pn,dec=1;c!=EOF && isdigit(c);c=getch())
     {
         *pn=10* (*pn)+ (c-'0');  //calculate the decimal part//
         dec=dec*10;
     }
     *pn=*pn*sign/dec;
 }

 if((c=getch())=='e')
 {
      if((c=getch())=='-')
         for(*pn,pow=0.1;c!=EOF && isdigit(c);c=getch())
     {
         *pn=10* (*pn)+ (c-'0');  
         dec=dec/10;
     }
     else 
     {
         ungetch(c);
         for(*pn,pow=1.0;c!=EOF && isdigit(c);c=getch())
         {
             *pn=10* (*pn)+ (c-'0');  
             dec=dec*10;
         }
     }
*pn=*pn*sign*dec;
 }
if(c!=EOF)
    ungetch(c);
return c;
 }




#define BUFSIZE 100

char buf[BUFSIZE];      /* bufer for ungetch */
int bufp = 0;           /* next free position in buf */

 int getch(void)         /* get a (possibly pushed-back) character */
{
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c)     /* push character back on input */
{
       if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
              printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
      else
              buf[bufp++] = c;
}
```

Comment: I advise you to format your code better; K&R is a good example.  Well formatted code is easier for the eye, and easier to understand.  Also, don't use TABs, as this messes up the layout in environments with other TAB widths.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many issues in your program. Here are a few ones:

```
dec=dec*10;
```

There are some valid code paths in your program where `dec` is uninitialized.

```
char c,sign,dec;

/* ... */ 

if(c!=EOF)
```

`EOF` is a negative `int` so `c` has to be declared as an `int` not as a `char`.

Comment: just to clarify, EOF is -1, and it has to be an integer, right? btw, I checked my program and I meant to use another variable pow instead of dec in the other code path where I deal with exponents.

Comment: While `EOF` is usually defined as -1, the standard only requires that it be a negative integer. The general intention is that functions that return a character value will return either something that fits into an `unsigned char`, OR `EOF`. This means that there are 257 possible return values, so your variable needs to be an `int`.

Comment: @user2309838 as put in the answer the requirement is `EOF` is a negative `int`. So the value can be something different than `-1` and the type cannot be different than `int` (`signed char` for example which is an integer type is not OK).

Answer (score 0):

```
int getfloat(float *pn){
    int c,sign,dec;
    float pow, tmp;

    while(isspace(c=getch()))
        ;
    if(!isdigit(c) && c!=EOF && c!='-' && c!='+'){//&&c!='.'
        ungetch(c);
        return 0;
    }
    sign=(c=='-')?-1:1;
    if(c=='-'||c=='+')
        c=getch();
    if(!isdigit(c)){
        ungetch(c);
        return -1;
    }
    for(*pn=0;c!=EOF && isdigit(c);c=getch())
        *pn = 10* (*pn)+ (c-'0');  //calculate the integer part//
    *pn *= sign;

    if(c=='.'){
        c = getch();
        tmp=0;
        for(dec=1;c!=EOF && isdigit(c);c=getch()){
            tmp=10 * tmp + (c-'0');  //calculate the decimal part//
            dec=dec*10;
        }
        *pn = *pn + sign * tmp / dec;
    }

    if(c=='e'){
        c=getch();
        sign=(c=='-')?-1:1;
        if(c=='-')
            c=getch();
        for(tmp=0;c!=EOF && isdigit(c);c=getch())
            tmp=10 * tmp + (c-'0');
        printf("debug:%f\n", sign*tmp);
        *pn=*pn*powf(10.0f, sign*tmp);
    }
    if(c!=EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return c;
}
```

Still have problems maybe

Answer (score 0):

What is `for (*pn, ...)` meant to achieve? This is the initialisation phase of the loop, but `*pn` just gets what `pn` is pointing to and throws it away.

Comment: that's right. I'm not intended to initialize *pn in the loop. I'll just delete it.